# whitespace in url - alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to post a http request using alamofire. my request is as follows:

```
let url = "\(myBaseURL)/{name:adriana lima}"
Alamofire.request(url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!, method: .post)
```

I tried some encoding types such as :

> urlFragmentAllowed , whitespaces

but they're not working.

I know if i use parameters, whitespace would be handled but in this case, i have to pass parameters inside of url. but it results error. how can i post this and how should i encode it ?

Comment: Try `NSURLComponents` it escapes urls implicitly.

Comment: @vadian could you give a sample form using NSURLComponents with alamofire?

Comment: I don't use Alamofire. Look into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcomponents). It's pretty straightforward. I'm sure there is Alamofire API which takes an URL rather than a string.

Answer (score 8):

You need to encode the URL before passing it to alamofire method. using `addingPercentEncoding`.

```
let urlString = "\(myBaseURL)/{name:adriana lima}"
guard let encodedURL = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else {
    //Invalid URL
    return 
}
```